# Pycharm Professional saying "Cannot find reference '>>' in 'function'" when I use print >> in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, code-inspection

I am using Pycharm to program something in Python 2.7 which runs in another application. I was using the Community edition but just switched to Professional. There are parts of the code where I use the "print >> " command. PyCharm Community was fine with this, but as soon as I switched to Professional it highlighted every single ">>" and put a line saying "Cannot find reference '>>' in 'function'" in the Problems tab for each one. The program still runs just fine but it's annoying, and turning off "Unresolved references" meant I missed some actual problems, so I turned it back on. Any way to fix this? I tried the invalidate cache and restart thing already. The interpreter being used is definitely Python 2.7.

It also complains when I am writing my unit tests and put a temporary statement like "print variable", it underlines the space between "print" and the variable in red and says "End of statement expected", but when I run the code (in PyCharm this time) it throws no errors and prints just fine. So PyCharm knows it's Python 2.7 but the inspector doesn't, I guess?

I also had similar issues with it highlighting every single function from gtk as an unresolved reference, but I was able to use one of the "quick fixes" to add those to the ignore list while that option doesn't come up for the "print >>" error.

I am expecting for the inspector to inspect the code for the syntax of the version of Python I'm actually using.

I've also tried right-clicking on every listed problem and saying "Suppress for a statement" but that puts a comment in my code which I don't want to be there and is time consuming. I've also tried to put things like "print >>" and ">>" in the "ignore" list for the unresolved references inspection but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Edit: I know it's been over a year, but after complaining to some friends, we seem to have found the source of the problem.
So if you look at my name, you may notice it has an accented é in it. My user folder on my computer also has this accented é. I went through hell trying to get Python 2.7 to work at all because of this - it turns out it's hard-coded to use ascii encoding, and not only do I have to put # coding=utf-8 at the top of my files, I had to go into the Python 2.7 files themselves and change the encoding from ascii to utf-8.

A friend of mine tried to replicate the issues I was having - it didn't happen for them. Only difference was the changes I had to make to my Python to get it working despite my name. So while I didn't think it would be my name... apparently it is.

I doubt anyone will ever see this, but I figured I'd update just in case someone in the same situation ever comes across this on Google. It's your name again. Yeah, I hate that Python doesn't like non-English names too. Unfortunately you'll have to deal with it for Python to work. Sorry, man.

Comment: @dskrypa The application I am writing for (Gwyddion) *requires* that plugins be written in Python 2.7. I would be using Python 3 if I could. This is unhelpful.

Comment: If you've found an answer to your own question, post it as an answer, rather than just an addendum to the question. You can accept it, to show others who find this in google searches or wherever that it worked for you.